# Function gets a maximum and a minimum

Tags: analysis, continuity, maxima-minima

Let $S^2$ be the surface of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $T\colon S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map.

How could we justify that $T$ gets a maximum $T_{\text{max}}$ and a minimum $T_{\text{min}}$ and that there is a point $x_0\in S^2$ with $T(x_0)=T(-x_0)$ ?

Could you give me a hint? I don't really have an idea.

Comment: See [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk–Ulam_theorem) for the second part of your question. That $T$ admits maximum and minimum follows from Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $S^2$ is compact, the maximum and the minimum of $T$ must be attained somewhere.

Suppose that you never have $T(x)=T(-x)$. Then the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&S^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&T(x)-T(-x)\end{array}$$is continuous and it has no zeros. But this is impossible, because if $f(x)>0$, then $f(-x)<0$ and, since $S^2$ is connected, $f(S^2)$ must be connected too and therefore it is an interval.

Comment: Why is $S^2$ compact?

Comment: Because it is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @MaryStar Because is closed and bounded.

Comment: A set from a metric space is called bounded if it is contained in a sphere with finite radius. We have that $S^2$ has radius equal to $1$. So since $S^2$ is contained in each sphere of finite radius $r\geq 1$, it follwos that $S^2$ is bounded. To show that $S^2$ is closed, we have to show that the complement is open. We have that $\notin \overline{S^2}\Rightarrow \|x\|\neq 1$, that means that $\|x\|<1$ or $\|x\|>1$. The points with norm less than $1$ are on the open ball with center $0)$ and radius $1$. The points with norm greater than $1$. What does it hold for this case?

Comment: About the second part: I understand!! ALso an other question.. Is there a value $T\in (T_{\text{min}}, T_{\text{max}})$ that appears only at one point on $S^2$ ? Could you give me a hit how we could check that?

Comment: @MaryStar That's another question. Please post it as such.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your answer at the original question!!